# Python - Pygame - Learning get_pressed

Tags: python, object, keyboard, pygame

I am learning python as well as pygame. I am struggling a bit with finding the issue in my code. When I hold down a key and press another key at the same time, and then let go of them in the same order I press them, it sometimes makes my little character move backwards in the opposite direction.

Here is my code that I am struggling with:

```
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # if user clicked close
        running = False # flag done to exit this loop


# all game logic / controls should go below this comment
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if keystate[K_SPACE]:
            print ('pressed space')
            player.move_up = True
        elif keystate[K_RIGHT]:
            print ('pressed right')
            player.move_right = True
        elif keystate[K_LEFT]:
            print ('pressed left')
            player.move_left = True
    elif event.type == KEYUP:
        if keystate[K_SPACE]:
            print ('released space')
            player.move_up = False
        elif keystate[K_RIGHT]:
            print ('released right')
            player.move_right = False
        elif keystate[K_LEFT]:
            print ('released left')
            player.move_left = False


if player.move_up:
    player.pos[1] -= 3
if player.move_up == False:
    if player.pos[1] < ground_level:
        player.pos[1] +=3
if player.move_right:
    player.pos[0] += 5
if player.move_left:
    player.pos[0] -= 5`
```

So far I don't have any actual physics, and he just flies around. But that's okay, I just want to iron out the issues that I am already having.

Answer (score 1):

You never update `keystate`'s value on a `KEYUP` event. Thus, it still has whatever values it had whenever the last `KEYDOWN` event fired.

To fix this, change this...

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

to this:

```
if event.type in (KEYDOWN, KEYUP):
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Comment: To add, you choose either [1] event based keydown/up or [2] getstate for key input. -- If you want WASD type movement, use getstate for that. If you want on-press/click, then use events for that.